# Regex Match 2 Digits 0 to 9

Tags: regex

i'm new to regex 
i'm trying to match a case where  there are 2 digits both can be 
from 0-9

something along the lines of

```
[0-9][0-9]
```

for example :

> 11  10  01

Comment: Please describe your problem better: you need to match all occurrences of numbers with two digits of if the string consists of two digits only?

Comment: You should always add the language, because regex has its small differences from language to language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Including the @Kobi's suggestion.

```
(?<![0-9])[0-9]{2}(?![0-9])
```

Comment: You can also do `(?<!\d)\d{2}(?!\d)` - these usually look better when you reverse the logic: http://rubular.com/r/oXD27VErwY

Comment: No problem! I really *don't* need credit in the answer though `:)` . You may want to also include a short explanation of why it works. Oh, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 5):

I believe `^\d{2}(\s\d{2})+$` should fit your needs.

Test this Regex at [Regex101](http://regex101.com)

PS: Learn, try for your own and come to us without just the problem but with some efforts next time. :)

Answer (score 5):

What you need are word boundaries, try

```
\b\d{2}\b
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?31qna).

`\b` matches a wordboundary (in a lot of languages), thats the change from a wordcharacter to a non wordcharacter. Means, the regex would match 2 digits, if there is **no digit or letter before and ahead**.

`\d` works in most regex flavours as a shortcut for [0-9], some does not support this shortcut and some use the Unicode version and match any kind of number with `\d`